# Angular View with *ngFor Not Rendering Data

Tags: javascript, angular, lambda, arrow-functions

I'm new to Angular, but familiar with Javascript.

I'm setting up a CRUD for a demo and can't get this list to loop over data returned from our API.

The data is loading fine, I can see it in the console. But the `*ngFor` below does not render any `<li>`s.

pages.component.html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p>Pages</p>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let page of pages">
                {{page.Name}}
            </li>
            <li>this shows up.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

pages.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PageService } from '../page.service';
import { Page } from '../page';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pages',
  templateUrl: './pages.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pages.component.css']
})
export class PagesComponent implements OnInit {
    pages: Page[];

    getPages(): void {
        this.pageService.all().subscribe(function(pages) {
            console.log(pages);
            this.pages = pages;
        }
    }

    constructor(private pageService: PageService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getPages();
    }
}
```

Like I said, the data shows up in the console, so I think it must be in the view.

Answer (score 0):

It was in the TS after all.

My `getPages` function was using a lambda instead of an arrow-function.  I thought they were semantically identical. But the lambda was not properly bound to `this`.

So when I wrote to `this.pages` it was not saving to the component's `pages` member, rather the anonymous function itself.

```
getPages(): void {
    this.pageService.all().subscribe(function(pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }
}
```

Should be this instead:

```
getPages(): void {
    this.pageService.all().subscribe(pages => this.pages = pages);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In ts file:

```
getPagesFromView() {
    If (this.pages.length > 0) {
        return this.pages;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside the `subscribe` callback the context of `this` is different. So you can either use arrow function or `bind` & pass the context of this

```
getPages(): void {
        this.pageService.all().subscribe(function(pages) {
            console.log(pages);
            this.pages = pages;
        }.bind(this))
    }
```